# Can you cut and paste code between android apps

Tags: android

I have had 4 apps mad for me. Lets call them App1 and App2 are for apple and App3 and App 4 are for android.
There is the same functions in apps 1 and 2 for apple and 3 and 4 for android. As it is the same can the code be cut and pasted rather than rewritten.

Comment: You would have to port code between java and objective-C; you can't copy and paste ObjectiveC and expect it to work in java.

Comment: what are you trying to say ?

Answer (score 1):

iOS is Objective-C/Swift, Android ist Java... so no, you can't.
You have to convert the code in the corresponding language.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want, but i see two options:

### Sharing code between two android apps

You can write your own library project and add this project to both of your apps

### Share code between two platforms

It is impossible, but you can use an alternative: any web server which will execute your code.